# Can't access modal component content in ngx bootstrap

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, ngx-bootstrap

The content value of the component initialized as a popup doesnt contain it's properties, it only has the prototype.

It looks like a life-cycle issue where the component is not entirely initialized when .show() returns.
I've tried defining the properties on the constructor and also in the onInit() method

ModalCaller.ts

```
const bsModalRef = this.getModalService().show(ExampleComponent);
return bsModalRef.content.onClose;
```

ExampleComponent.component.ts

```
export class ExampleComponent {
  public onClose: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  onSubmit() {
    this.onClose.next(true);
  }
```

[image: Result]
So when I want to access the content it's empty or not initialized yet, but the .show() method returns void so I cant know when the component is ready

Comment: I don't understand the issue but one thing you can try by using 'ngafterviewinit' life cycle. This ensures the DOM is ready to handle any event.